# How to implement Failover in Lucene?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I am currrently running a single server Lucene search engine for my platform - and would like to explore the possibility of deploying another server (mostly for failover reasons)

I am using a Lucene.Net driver.

Any suggestions for best practices to do so with a Lucene index of about 100,000 documents?

Comment: Are you familiar with elasticsearch or solr?

Comment: this is very hard to give you pointers without more details about the basic structure of your app, I'd recommend you to look into Solr instead of using Lucene directly